# Как нажать несколько раз одну и туже кнопку подряд?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было нажать несколько раз одну и туже кнопку подряд?

Пробовал так с задержкой в две секунды - ничего не вышло:

```
if ($('#double_your_btc_bet_lose').html() !== '' && multiplier == 3 ) {
   multiplier++; 
   $('#double_your_btc_2x').click(); 
   function firstStep() {} 
   function secondStep() {} 
   firstStep(); 
   setTimeout('secondStep()', 2000); 
   $('#double_your_btc_2x').click(); 
}
```

Comment: Сначала нажать первый раз на кнопку, затем нажать второй раз на нее

Comment: if ($('#double_your_btc_bet_lose').html() !== '' && multiplier == 3 ) {
multiplier++; $('#double_your_btc_2x').click();
function firstStep(){
}
function secondStep(){
}
firstStep();
setTimeout('secondStep()',2000);
$('#double_your_btc_2x').click();
пробовал так

Comment: с задержкой в две секунды - ничего не вышло

Comment: Вопрос свой отредактируйте пожалуйста. Не надо писать код в комментариях.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function click(e, n, t) {
  if(e != undefined && n != undefined && n > 0 && t >= 100){
    var m = 0;
    var int = setInterval(function() {
      if(m == n){
        clearInterval(int);
      }else{
        m++;
        $(e).click();
      };
    }, t);
  };
};

$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    console.log('Нажали!');
  });
  click('button', 5, 2000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Нажми на меня</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0 i < 100; i++) { // нажимаем 100 раз подряд на кнопку
    $('#button').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {$('#button').click();}};
```

Comment: var i = 0 i < 2; i++ 
в этом выражении ненужно поставить запятую перед i<2?